# Paginator.getPaginate() not working in Python Boto3 for Redshift Data API

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-redshift, boto3

I am using Boto3 in python to get the data. I have created an API with the help of Flask in Python. I am firing a query and trying to retrieve the data, but it is too large hence trying to use Paginator but it returns NULL everytime.

```
paginator = DataClient.get_paginator('get_statement_result')
PaginatorResponse = paginator.paginate(
    Id=request.args.get('Id'),
    PaginationConfig={
        'MaxItems': request.args.get('max-items'),
        'StartingToken': request.args.get('start-token')
    }
)
RESPONSE['redshift'] = PaginatorResponse
response = app.response_class(
    response = json.dumps(RESPONSE ,sort_keys=True,indent=1,default=default),
    status = STATUSCODE,
    mimetype = 'application/json'
)
```

This is the paginator code which returns NULL on same query ID which I use in the get_statement_result directly. Here is the code for the same:

```
RecordsResponse = DataClient.get_statement_result(Id=request.args.get('Id'))
RESPONSE['redshift'] = RecordsResponse
RESPONSE['records'] = convertRecords(RecordsResponse)
response = app.response_class(
    response = json.dumps(RESPONSE ,sort_keys=True,indent=1,default=default),
    status = STATUSCODE,
    mimetype = 'application/json'
)
```

Result ScreenShot from **Get Statement Result**
[image]

Result ScreenShot from **Get Paginator**
[image]

Not able to understand where I am going wrong, and how to get it done.